# can't get the user's address in mongoose / nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

When the app loads it fetches initialData Array of objects from the backend where I have all the info I need, like categories,orders,products etc. Inside the orders array i have all the info about the users ordered items, status etc. I want to load the users address, when he filled up the address form that address.I have that address stored inside address.js-> UserAddress model/schema. So I want to load the users address inside orders array.
plz help me get the users address inside the orders array so that i can display the users address inside my admin-app->orders card, i'm new at this so I'm unable to figure it out on my own.

here is my orderSchema

```
    const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    addressId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "UserAddress.address",
      required: true,
    },
    totalAmount: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    items: [
      {
        productId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Product",
        },
        payablePrice: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        purchasedQty: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    paymentStatus: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["pending", "completed", "cancelled", "refund"],
      required: true,
    },
    paymentType: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["cod", "card"],
      required: true,
    },
    orderStatus: [
      {
        type: {
          type: String,
          enum: ["ordered", "packed", "shipped", "delivered"],
          default: "ordered",
        },
        date: {
          type: Date,
        },
        isCompleted: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);
```

here is my address schema:

```
const addressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    min: 3,
    max: 50,
  },
  mobileNumber: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  pinCode: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  locality: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    min: 10,
    max: 100,
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    min: 10,
    max: 100,
  },
  cityDistrictTown: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  state: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    required: true,
  },
  landmark: {
    type: String,
    min: 10,
    max: 100,
  },
  alternatePhone: {
    type: String,
  },
  addressType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["home", "work"],
    required: true,
  },
});

// B
const userAddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "User",
    },
    address: [addressSchema],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

mongoose.model("Address", addressSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("UserAddress", userAddressSchema);
```

here is the get initial data where i get all the data/response:

```
exports.initialData = async (req, res) => {
  const categories = await Category.find({}).exec();

  const products = await Product.find({ createdBy: req.user._id })
    .select("_id name price quantity slug description productPictures category")
    .populate({ path: "category", select: "_id name" })
    .exec();

  const orders = await Order.find({})
    .populate("items.productId", "name")
    .exec();
  res.status(200).json({
    categories: createCategories(categories),
    products,
    orders,
  });
};
```

here is the response of initial data:
[image: response]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `$lookup` aggregation from the order schema to the address schema to fetch the address of the user via the `user` field.

More info on MongoDb `$lookup` aggregation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)